# How to retain the values in the text field with Radio buttons using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have some code that updates form fields based on a radio button being clicked:

html

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="extra" value="add_extra_new">Add New Extra</label>
    <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="extra" value="exists" checked="checked">Existing Extras</label>
</div>
<span id="add_new">Name of Extra :</span>
<input id="add_more" type="text" name="nameOfExtra" >
<span id="existing">Exsisting Extras :</span>
<select id="extra-select" name="extras">
    <option>deep cleaning</option>
</select>
<span class="extra-heading">Set Price :</span>
<input id="price" type="text" name="price">
```

javascript

```
var new_extra = document.getElementById("add_new");
new_extra.style.display = "none";
var extraText = document.getElementById("add_more");
extraText.style.display = "none";
var extraExist = document.getElementById("existing");
var extra_dropdown = document.getElementById("extra-select");
function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
    if (event.value === "add_extra_new") {
        console.log(event.value);
        new_extra.style.display = "block";
        extraText.style.display="block";
        extraExist.style.display="none";
        extra_dropdown.style.display="none";
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked');
        $('input[type="text"]').val("");
    } else {
        extraExist.style.display="block";
        extra_dropdown.style.display="block";
        new_extra.style.display = "none";
        extraText.style.display="none";
    }
    }
```

JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:{ "extraOption" : extra_option}, 
    dataType : "JSON", 
    url : "login.php", 
    success:function(response){
        var data = response.data; 
        if(data){
            $.each(data, function (key, name) {    
                $('#price').val(name['price']);
                $('#hour').val(name['hours']);
                $('#minute').val(name['minutes']);
            });
        } else {        
            $('#once').val('');
            $('#reoccurence').val('');
            $('#discount').val('');
        }      
    }
});
```

login.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","price");
$result2 = array();
if (isset($_POST['extraOption'])) { 
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from extras where name_of_extra                                                                                     ='$_POST[extraOption]'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {        
       $result2['data'][] = array(
           "price" => $row['price'],
           "hours" => $row['hours'],
           "minutes" => $row['minutes']
       );
    }
    echo json_encode($result2);
}
```

**Initial state**

[image]

As you can see, form's fields have initial values.

Now when "Add New Extra" radio button is clicked, text fields get emptied because of my code **else** part.

**After "Add New Extra" click**

[image]

My problem is: if I then click on the "Existing Extra" the text fields do not recover their initial value.

[image]

What should I do so the text fields get their initial value back (like in the first image) at this time?
Thank you.

Comment: Add your all important script in question please.

Comment: HTML of the form and its JS part.

Comment: @Adnanhaider now see the question again i edited it.

Comment: if you click on existing extras. All existing extras will populated in dropdown. Correct ?

Comment: see when the page loads then first image i post will show. now then i selected other radio button **Add New Extra** . then i again click on the **Existing Extra** then the data in the input fields will loss. I want the data rest in the text Field. hope you will understand what i m saying.:) @Adnanhaider

Comment: I understand and i will guide you with best solution for you. When page loads first time from where you get data for existing extras ?.

Comment: from the database when I select any option.

Comment: So solution is that. you just have to make another ajax call when you select the existing radio button. understand ?

Comment: can you write the code for it I don't know how it works. please @Adnanhaider

Comment: Ok i will.  Let me know, on page loading existing extras loaded with ajax ?

Comment: No, the first option is **select** and when i select the option then the ajax will run. @Adnanhaider

Comment: Ok so i have to write code from scratch. Add the login.php file also in question. any other jJS where you using this variable extra_option add in question. I will check it and write the code soon. But this platform is not for this purpose.

Comment: then now what to do? :(@Adnanhaider

Comment: Add all those things which i mention in previous comment and i will check and answer.

Comment: @Adnanhaider editing was done now you can check no there is no other jQuery is used

Comment: login.php file ?

Comment: @Adnanhaider yeah i include it see.

Comment: Ok great i will look through it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **localStorage**, check this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio">
   <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="extra" value="add_extra_new">Add New Extra</label>
   <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="extra" value="exists" checked="checked">Existing
      Extras</label>
</div>

<span id="add_new">Name of Extra :</span>
<input id="add_more" type="text" name="nameOfExtra">

<span id="existing">Exsisting Extras :</span>
<select id="extra-select" name="extras">
   <option value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="deep cleaning">deep cleaning</option>
   <option value="dishes">dishes</option>
</select>

<span class="extra-heading">Set Price :</span>
<input id="price" type="text" name="price">
```

**JS**

```
var new_extra = document.getElementById("add_new");
   new_extra.style.display = "none";
   var extraText = document.getElementById("add_more");
   extraText.style.display = "none";
   var extraExist = document.getElementById("existing");
   var extra_dropdown = document.getElementById("extra-select");

      function myFunction(event) {
        if (event.value === "add_extra_new") {
            localStorage.setItem("pirce", $('#price').val());

            new_extra.style.display = "block";
            extraText.style.display = "block";
            extraExist.style.display = "none";
           extra_dropdown.style.display = "none";
           $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked');
           $('input[type="text"]').val("");
        } else {
           extraExist.style.display = "block";
           extra_dropdown.style.display = "block";
           new_extra.style.display = "none";
           extraText.style.display = "none";

          $('#price').val(localStorage.getItem("pirce"));
        }
     }

   $("#extra-select").on('change',function () {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: {"extraOption": $(this).val()},
         dataType: "JSON",
         url: "login.php",
         success: function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            if (data) {
               $.each(data, function (key, name) {
                  $('#price').val(name['price']);
                  $('#hour').val(name['hours']);
                  $('#minute').val(name['minutes']);
               });
            } else {
               $('#once').val('');
               $('#reoccurence').val('');
               $('#discount').val('');
            }
         }
      });
   });
```

**Login.php**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","price");
$result2 = array();
if (isset($_POST['extraOption'])) {
   $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from extras where name_of_extras ='$_POST[extraOption]'");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $result2['data'][] = array(
         "price" => $row['price'],
         "hours" => $row['hours'],
         "minutes" => $row['minutes']
      );
   }
   echo json_encode($result2);
}
```

**Explanation**

You need to check when ever user change the dropdown values.

Comment: @Puneet it is working you just have to replace with your code.

Comment: can u edit it and tell me where you will change the code.@adnanhaider

Comment: ("#extra-select").on('change',function () {});

Comment: select * from extras where name_of_extras

Comment: Added two option to dropdown.

Comment: Did you replace all js or not.?

Comment: yeah i replace it but not working its doing the same.

Comment: when you click on existing extras than you have to select the option from dropdown dishes or deep cleaning . Than ajax will get its price of selected extra. is this happening or something else ?

Comment: Yeah it got all the prices in the input field  but when i select the add new extra and i again click on the existing extra the the input fields empty and the select option remains same. You understand what i mean to say.

Comment: Is there any action on add new extra click ?. Are you saving data. what are you doing on this action ?

Comment: When i click on add new extra then existing  select option will hide and the input field visible see in javascript code.

Comment: So add new extras are saving anywhere. it just hiding and displaying action. So you want that when ever click on existing last selected value and its price should be there ?

Comment: yeah that i want .

Comment: For that you need to use JS localstorage. I updated my answer just copy the myFunction(event) definition and replace with older one in your code. it will works.

Comment: its really working thanks for helping me :) @adnanhaider

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48923739/9219620 see this question @adnanhaider

Answer (score 0):

use this to reset to initial value

```
$('radio[value=existing_data]').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.setprice').val(11);//these three line set value to inputs
    $('.min').val(10);
    $('.timehrs').val(1);
 }
});
```

**P.S** set select as per your need

Comment: thnku sir for replying my question but i don't getting what are you saying exactly.